# A collection of Puzzling Tools

Tags: support, faq, search

This post is a community-wiki compilation of useful puzzle tools and websites.

> If you find some useful source, please edit the according answer post to add it.
> Also add a short description, please.

#### Categories below:

- [Cipher Tools](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4922/5840)
- [Word Tools](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5035/5840)
- [Number Tools](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5034/5840)
- [Graphic Tools](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5033/5840)
- [Puzzle Tools](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5032/5840)
- [Geography Tools](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5038/5840)
- [Useful Information Sources](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5036/5840)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!! :D

Comment: Why isn't this list of tools on the main site?  It certainly is about puzzles themselves more than about the functioning of the site.

Comment: @humn; Originally I had this post on MathJax in mind : https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference, which is hosted on Meta. Several people have suggested it should be on the main site, but I don't know how to migrate it.

Answer (score 14):

#### Cipher Tools

- [**Rumkin**](http://rumkin.com/tools/cipher/) has a pretty neat collection of cipher tools for both encrypting and decrypting
- [**Vigenere Cipher Codebreaker**](http://www.mygeocachingprofile.com/codebreaker.vigenerecipher.aspx) can solve vigenere ciphers with or without the key.  (You will need sufficiently long ciphertext to break the cipher without a key.)
- [**Len Schulwitz**](http://lenschulwitz.com/base58) is useful for encoding/decoding those pesky base 58 numbers
- [**QuipQiup**](http://quipqiup.com/index.php) can attempt to solve simple substitution cryptograms automatically for you
- [**Rot13.com**](http://www.rot13.com/) for rot13/any other Caesar cipher. Already covered by Rumkin, but easier to remember url for quick encryption/decryption
- [**dcode.fr**](http://www.dcode.fr/tools-list) has many decryption tools sorted by different categories
- [**Cyberchef**](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/) is a multi tool for detecting encoding and performing several operations of decryption or encryption of data (and much more)
- [**Cryptii**](https://cryptii.com/) has a wide collection of encryption and decryption tools sorted by category. It allows multiple tools to be chained, but does not support decryption without the key.
- [**A1Z26@Planet Calc**](https://planetcalc.com/4881/). A=1, B=2, ..., Z=26. You know you want to...

Answer (score 8):

#### Graphics Tools

- [**RGB Color Wheel**](http://www.colorspire.com/rgb-color-wheel/) correlates colors to RGB (`#RRGGBB` and 255-255-255) and HSV ( °-%-%)
- [**GIF-Explode**](https://www.gif-explode.com/) is a web-tool to show individual frames of animated gif images. Just provide the link to the image.
- [**GeoGebra Tools**](https://www.geogebra.org/apps) are an online collection of tools for drawing geometries and mathematical content online.
- [**TinkerCAD**](https://www.tinkercad.com/) is a browser-based 3D modelling program. 
  The [REJBÄS](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/43286/5840) puzzle uses this [*example*](https://tinkercad.com/things/4S6ABYgmo3E).
- **[ezgif](https://ezgif.com/optimize)** is a very good gif editor with several tools including a compressor (transparency recommended), cropping and resizing.
- **[GIFgifs](http://gifgifs.com/optimizer/)** is another very good gif editor similar to the one above
- **[Jfly Color Universal Design](http://jfly.iam.u-tokyo.ac.jp/color/#pallet)** suggests colors to use in puzzle design
- **[Coblis](http://www.color-blindness.com/coblis-color-blindness-simulator/)** simulates different kinds of color vision for any picture

Answer (score 8):

#### Number Tools

- [**The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences**](http://oeis.org/) is useful for puzzles involving integer sequences
- [**Base Converter**](http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/) converts between binary, decimal, hexadecimal and ASCII
- [**Calculator Soup**](http://www.calculatorsoup.com) is a cornucopia of tools [(index)](http://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/) for manipulating numbers in myriad contexts, even sports
- [**Prime Factors Calculator**](http://www.javascripter.net/math/calculators/primefactorscalculator.htm) calculates the prime factors of integers less than $10^{20}$. Options for showing as a list (e.g. `7*7`) and in exponential form (e.g. `7^2`).
- [**Prime Factors Calculator**](http://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/math/prime-factors.php) calculates the prime factors of integers up to $10^{10}$. It shows prime factors: as a list, in exponential form, as a decomposition tree, and by ordinality
- [**What's Special About This Number?**](https://erich-friedman.github.io/numbers.html) is a trove of clues related to numbers
- [**One Million Digits of Pi**](http://www.piday.org/million/) for anything related to the constant π.
- [**Web 2.0 scientific calculator**](http://web2.0calc.com) for a scientific calculator and graphing tool (with ads)
- [**AnyDice**](http://anydice.com/) ouputs dice results distributions for any configuration of dice. Very flexible!
  <sub>( See this [puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46497/building-the-ideal-scrabble-dice-set) and [result](http://anydice.com/program/a08d) )</sub>

Answer (score 8):

#### Word Tools

- [**Litscape**](http://www.litscape.com/word_tools/word_search.html) has an extensive list of words finding tools (for example [pattern matching](http://www.litscape.com/word_tools/pattern_match.php), words [containing](http://www.litscape.com/word_tools/contains_minimally.php) or [made from](http://www.litscape.com/word_tools/contains_only.php) certain letters, [single word anagrams](http://www.litscape.com/word_tools/anagram.php), etc)
- [**Ceptimus Word Ladder**](http://ceptimus.co.uk/wordladder.php) solver, finds a word ladder from word A to word B
- [**Wordsmith's Advanced Anagramming**](http://wordsmith.org/anagram/advanced.html) is a multilingual, multi-word anagram solver with a range of options to restrict anagrams by word count, word lengths, repeats, white and black lists, etc.
- [**Anagram Solver**](http://anagram-solver.net) seems to have indexed the title of almost every Wikipedia article, among many other things.  If you're looking for an anagram involving proper names or obscure concepts, it can be very helpful.  You might have to search through a long list of results, though, and you'll have to put up with some fairly invasive ads.
- [**Iterative Anagram Solver**](http://boulter.com/anagram/) allows you to find multi-word anagrams iteratively, by selecting individual partial anagram words from the input, and then re-generating possible words from the remainder of letters.
- [**Regex Dictionary**](http://www.visca.com/regexdict/) allows you to search a dictionary with regular expressions, and is useful when Litscape's pattern matching isn't enough (assuming you know how to write a regex)
- [**Nutrimatic**](https://nutrimatic.org/) is another regex search (as well as offering anagramming), using a dictionary of words and phrases mined from Wikipedia.
- [**Qat**](https://www.quinapalus.com/cgi-bin/qat) is a powerful word constraint matcher which can sometimes allow for simpler syntax compared to regex searches.
- [**Onelook**](https://onelook.com/) offers a phrase pattern matcher and can sort candidate phrases by commonness.
- [**Thesaurus**](http://www.thesaurus.com/) allows you to find synonyms and antonyms for English words.
- [**Rhymer**](http://www.rhymer.com/) is a quick an easy tool for finding rhyming words.
- [**Google Sheets**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets) are a great tool for building and (community-)solving word-search puzzles on a regular grid. ([example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1th1GtVWP19uFHAnMsGKjO099OXUDH9W-gPc3k-sbg30/edit))
- [**Google Ngrams**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/) lets you search the frequency of word occurrences in books over time.

Answer (score 6):

#### Puzzle Tools

- [**Chess board editor**](http://www.apronus.com/chess/wbeditor.php) is an online interactive chessboard with PGN viewer and editor
- [**Sudoku Solver**](http://www.sudokuwiki.org/sudoku.htm) is a fully featured sudoku solver by Andrew Stuart
- [**Qhex Puzzle Tools**](https://tools.qhex.org/) contains a wide array of puzzling tools, including solving various logic puzzles (Masyu, Sudoku, Lights Out, Thermometers, Kakuro, Fill-a-Pix, Minesweeper, Hitori, Nurikabe, Tapa, Hasiwokakero, Numberlink, Shikaku, Fillomino, Nonograms, Dissections), word searches, some ciphers, and a word searching engine as well.

Answer (score 5):

#### Useful Information Sources

- [**Telephone Dialing Codes**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes) for countries, and also shows their flags
- [**Internet Movie DataBase**](http://www.imdb.com/) for film and TV references
- [**Runes**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runes) - for all things runey
- [**Wolfram|Alpha**](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) - computational knowledge engine

Answer (score 5):

#### Geography Tools

- [**Measure Distance on a Map**](https://www.freemaptools.com/measure-distance.htm) measures the distance and travel time between two places, with many options such as snapping to road or not, mode of transport (including different levels of car speeds) and units to measure in.
- [**London Underground map**](https://tfl.gov.uk/maps/track/tube) is a map that shows all the tube stations in London, England.
- [**Altitude map**](http://veloroutes.org/elevation/) lets you find the altitude in feet or meters of a certain place, searchable by address, city, or latitude/longitude.
- [**OpenStreetMap**](https://www.openstreetmap.org/) is an open-licensed map.
- [**CountryCode.org**](https://countrycode.org/) for ISO Country Codes, Telephone Codes, Population, etc.

Comment: Is a London Underground map really going to be an oft-used tool? It's not fixed, and why London in particular, why not, say, New York?

Comment: I don't know, @boboquack.

Comment: @boboquack Maybe someone will make a puzzle that's decoded with [Mornington Crescent](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Mornington_Crescent).