# Let's write a proper "Read Me First"

Tags: discussion, policy, new-users

Our site has a lot of rules.

One might even say, an awful lot.

It would be a very good idea to list the most relevant of them in one place somewhere (the tour seems like a decent option) so that we wouldn't need to give many a well-meaning newcomer a figurative kick in the face when they first try to post, and we explain exactly which meta posts and VTC reasons they should have presciently known in order to avoid the torrent of downvotes that resulted.

As answers, I'm hoping to see some concisely worded, basic rules on what one should post, and how. Along the lines of:

> - Mostly, our questions are puzzles of our own making.
> - Do not ever post someone else's puzzle as your own
> - A puzzle should have a unique solution clearly identifiable as such.
> - The tag wikis will sometimes contain a section on "what (not) to do"

and so on.

Having these clearly stated would make the first step into PSE a lot easier to take, I believe.

Comment: Maybe a small guide for the 'obscure' community customs should be given somewhere as well! (such as rot13)

Comment: @Adam Oh, yes, very much yes.

Comment: Oh, and spoiler tax syntax (and formatting workarounds) too.

Comment: Maybe a separate meta post should be made for the purpose of the guide and linked at the bottom of the "Read Me First"

Comment: @Bass is't there how to ask? guide on puzzle meta like it is there on stackoverflow?

Comment: @Sayed Mohd Ali Maybe the idea here is "Made by us for us" sort of thing-it's better than the Overflow guide since it comes directly from us instead?

Comment: @RewanDemontay but that doesn't lead to lot of debates? I saw many questions where we try to makes rules to avoid debates but that leads to more debates... both positive side and negative side have high voted good and & justified points. and that leads to some good question got downvoted and the similar question got upvoted because of views not because of rules..

Comment: @SayedMohdAli True.

Comment: I've already gathered a lot of useful links in one place [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5824/5373). I move that we [meta-tag:faq]-ify all those posts (and maybe some others too) and then summarise the rules therein as you suggest.

Answer (score 5):

Since the question is getting a lot of support, but there are no answers yet, I'm starting this CW on Rand's idea: FAQify the posts in [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5824/5373) and summarise the rules.

Since I lack the power to add the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tags, I'm just writing some summaries here, grouped by the newcomers action for which they are relevant. Most links are still missing, as are probably some other conventions that it would be useful for a newcomer to know.

---

### This community wiki answer is a work in progress, and not yet complete.

---

### Asking:

- Our questions are mostly [puzzles of our own invention](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4535/36023).

  - Puzzles should have a [unique answer identifiable as such](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles).
  - Questions that look like maths homework [will be closed](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2784/36023).
- [Asking questions related to puzzles and puzzle design is also ok](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).
- Respect copyrights. Only use material you have a permission to use.

  - If you post a puzzle you didn't create yourself, always [attribute](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) the original author.
- The common practise is to accept the first correct answer, but you are free to accept any answer by whichever criteria you like.
- Avoid major changes to questions after they have been answered.

  - Interactive puzzles are [very limited, if not discouraged](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6779/56238) as a result.
- It's ok to add [hints](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5005/when-should-i-add-hints-to-my-puzzle) to questions, but waiting 24 hours before doing so is appreciated.
- Some tag wikis provide good advice on what (not) to do when asking. 
  Typical examples include "[What is a XYZ™ item](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5811/what-is-an-xyz-item-puzzles-what-not-to-do)", "[Number Sequences](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5712/number-sequence-puzzles-what-not-to-do)" and "[Code Puzzles](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do)". `TODO: Add more examples`

### Answering:

- An answer to a puzzle should always explain why it's the correct answer.
- Partial answers are [ok, but not always so](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6706/36023).
- Use spoiler tags `>!` at the start of lines to hide the crucial parts of the answer from accidental views.

### Commenting:

- If you have a minor improvement to an existing answer, add a comment rather than a new answer.
- Rot13 encryption is sometimes used to hide possible spoilers in comments. @Alconja's nice [script](https://stackapps.com/questions/7927/automated-rot13-spoiler-comments) can encrypt/ decrypt rot13 upon mouseover.

### Voting:

- Use upvotes and downvotes as you please. When downvoting, adding a constructive comment is much appreciated.

### Other:

- A collection of helpful tools to assist you can be found [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4921/a-collection-of-puzzling-tools).
- If you need help, the easiest way is to ask at [The Sphinx's Lair](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-sphinxs-lair).