# Is there anything good to know (that isn't already said to the user / written down on some page)?

Tags: discussion

I'm very new to Puzzling. Are there any unwritten rules, stuff, or anything related that is good to know? (Especially about how to structure a puzzle when posting but all tips are helpful.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let's write a proper "Read Me First"](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6701/lets-write-a-proper-read-me-first) (though there are still a few things not in that post that you might still be wondering about)