# Learning to solve puzzles for new users

Tags: support, new-users

I am a new user, now that I have a bit more time I would like to learn more about how to improve in solving puzzles.
Most of the time when I attempt to solve a puzzle I keep using the same set of skills that I know.
I saw that there is post with a [collection of puzzling tools](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4921/a-collection-of-puzzling-tools) but I rarely think to use them.

My question is more like "Can you give tips and advise how to start?"
Can I request a puzzle in some topic?
And lastly, is there community chat or something similar for this site?

Answer (score 5):

Tips and advice how to start are very broad and personal, they depend on a lot of things like whether English is your native language or not (if not, better not start with crosswords) and your mathematics skills. It will also depend on what type of puzzles you like. Stack Exchange Q&A works best when the question and its answers have limited scope and are relevant for many people, including future visitors. A question about solving tips for a particular type of puzzle could work on the main site, e.g.

- [Tips for solving poem riddles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/4574/11110)
- [Number sequence solving strategies](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/74496/11110) (though it also deals with tips for *making* them)

> And lastly, is their community chat or something similar for this site?

Yes, there is a chatroom for Puzzling Stack Exchange, [The Sphinx's Lair](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-sphinxs-lair), and it's probably the best place to place a request for a particular type of puzzle, or general help for solving puzzles, if you ask politely. Please keep in mind we're all volunteers and might prefer spending time solving and creating puzzles instead.